# BarButtonItem Doesn't Show button after added

Tags: iphone, swift

I want custom navigation item as `facebook` app.
Have two buttons and one `UISearchBar`. Buttons is `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem`. `UISearchBar` is `titleView`. 
to make searchbar in titleview become wide i removed two buttons by set it to nil as image below. and i add two buttons again when `searchBarCancelButton` clicked but the  buttons  doesn't shown. 
Could u help me ?  [image]

when click `searchBarCancelButton` i want it to show as below 
[image]

Code I have try:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil 
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("info", buttonfor: "left"), animated: false)
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("more_‌​icon", buttonfor: "right"), animated: false)
}

extension MainviewCtrl : UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = nil
    }
}
}

extension MainviewCtrl : UISearchBarDelegate    {

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("info", buttonfor: "left"), animated: false)
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("more_icon", buttonfor: "right"), animated: false)
}
}

class MainviewCtrl: UIViewController , UISearchControllerDelegate {

lazy var searchController : UISearchController = {

    let _searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    _searchController.searchBar.delegate   = self
    _searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    _searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
    var textFieldInsideSearchBar = _searchController.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
    textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return _searchController
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.titleView   = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
    addBarButtonItems()
}
func addBarButtonItems(){
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = getBarButtonItem("info", buttonfor: "left")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = getBarButtonItem("more_icon", buttonfor: "right")
}
func getBarButtonItem(imagename : String , buttonfor : String)-> UIBarButtonItem!{
    let image = (UIImage(named: imagename))!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    switch buttonfor.lowercaseString {
    case "left":
        return (UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(MainviewCtrl.infoAction)))
    case "right":
        return (UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(MainviewCtrl.moreAction)))
    default : break ;
    }
    return UIBarButtonItem()
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = nil
        }
    }
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("info", buttonfor: "left"), animated: false)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(getBarButtonItem("more_icon", buttonfor: "right"), animated: false)
    }

Comment: please update your question and add the code there with proper formatting.

Comment: @Daniel May be the problem is when you cancel the search it will call `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` and set the barItems but after that it will also call `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` and making it nil again, try to put break point and check that.

Comment: @Umair Afzal  thank you ^_^ it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateSearchResultsForSearchController` will get called again after you click cancel button and make those items `nil`. you can check if the search controller is active before setting them to `nil` in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil && searchController.active {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil 
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome:) Feel free to accept this answer if it helped solve your problem.